# Getting error 403 (CSRF token missing or incorrect)

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-csrf

I'm need some email form and I'm trying this:

views.py

```
def send_email(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = EmailForm()
        return render_to_response('mail_form.html', {'email_form': form})

    form = EmailForm(request.POST, request.FILES)   
    if form.is_valid():
        subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
        message = form.cleaned_data['message']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        attach = request.FILES['attach']
        try:
            mail = EmailMessage(subject, message, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [email])
            mail.attach(attach.name, attach.read(), attach.content_type)
            mail.send()
            return render(request, 'mail_form.html', {'message': 'Sent email to %s'%email})
        except:
            return render(request, 'mail_form.html', {'message': 'Either the attachment is too  big or corrupt'})
        return render(request, 'mail_form.html', {'message': 'Unable to send email. Please try again later'})
```

forms.py

```
class EmailForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    attach = forms.Field(widget=forms.FileInput)
    message = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea)
```

mail_form.html

```
...
{{message}}
<form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ email_form.as_p }}
    <input type ="submit"  name = "send" value = "Send"/>
</form>
...
```

But constantly I get an error 403. I tried different solutions from the web, but nothing helped. What I'm doing wrong? I'm understand that something wrong with csrf in views.py, but don't understand where is the problem concretely.

Comment: Your indenting is not correct.  Fix it.

Comment: @7stud fixed, thanks

Comment: Do you have the CSRF middleware enabled `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware`?

Comment: What version of django are you using?

Comment: Answer of Pythonista seems correct, at least I don't get 403 anymore

Comment: Yes, CSRF middleware is enabled. I'm using Django 1.9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is `render_to_reponse`. It doesn't have the context instance you can add it, but `render` handles this for you so why not just it instead. Also you can restructure your view to be a bit cleaner.

Here's one example.

```
def send_email(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EmailForm(request.POST, request.FILES)   
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            attach = request.FILES['attach']
            try:
                mail = EmailMessage(subject, message, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [email])
                mail.attach(attach.name, attach.read(), attach.content_type)
                mail.send()
                messages.succes(request, 'Sent an email to %s' % email)
            except:
                messages.error(request, 'Either the attachment is too  big or corrupt')
    else:
        form = EmailForm()
        messages.info(request, "Send an email!")
    return render(request, 'mail_form.html', {'email_form': form})
```

Then you can use `{% if messages %}` in your template to display your messages to the user / iterate over them and display.

`messages` here is from `django.contrib` so you'd need to do `from django.contrib import messages`

Comment: Thanks, it works! 
I'll read about the difference between render and render_to_response!

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `render_to_response` from `django.shortcuts`
2. Use in `render_to_response` `context_instance = RequestContext(request)`

This must fix your problem with csrf token or read https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/csrf/

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your view.py like this

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import RequestContext
def send_email(request):
if request.method != 'POST':
    form = forms.EmailForm()
    return render_to_response('mail_form.html', {'email_form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

......
......
```

Answer (score 0):

> What version of django are you using?

Well, obviously you are using `render()` in part of your code.  The problem is in your GET code--you are using `render_to_response()`:

```
if request.method != 'POST':
    form = EmailForm()
    return render_to_response('mail_form.html', {'email_form': form})
```

Instead use render():

```
    return render(request, 'mail_form.html', {'email_form': form} )
```

See the [example in the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#the-view).

The reason you need to do that is because with csrf tokens you need to:

1. Insert the csrf token in your form.
2. Include the csrf token as a cookie in the headers of the request/response.

`render()` accomplishes #2, but `render_to_response()` does not--unless you specifically tell it to, which you did not.  In any case, the [django 1.9 docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response) state:

> **render_to_response()**
>
> This function preceded the introduction of render() and works
>   similarly except that it doesn’t make the request available in the
>   response. ***It’s not recommended*** and is likely to be deprecated in the
>   future.